# How to wrap multiple context provider with routers in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add multiple provider to my app. But it does not work. The app in here https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-providers-ohpcl?file=/src/App.js
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the children, the nested JSX is sent along with the props as `children` property. In the provider components just add the received children in the returned JSX.

```
const AboutProvider = (props) => {
  return (
    <AboutContext.Provider
      value={{ value: "welcome to about page" }}
    >{props.children}</AboutContext.Provider>
  );
};

const HomeContext = createContext();
const HomeProvider = (props) => {
  return (
    <HomeContext.Provider
      value={{ value: "This is home page" }}
    >{props.children}</HomeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `HomeProvider` and `AboutProvider` components are not rendering their child components.

In react, every component receives a special property named children.

Please refer https://codeburst.io/a-quick-intro-to-reacts-props-children-cb3d2fce4891

In your code, add `{props.children}` to render child components like

```
//A parameter is required to access the children special property
const HomeProvider = (props) => {
  return (
    <HomeContext.Provider
      value={{ value: "This is home page" }}
    >
        {props.children}
    </HomeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```